Why does Windows (and most OSes that I know of) require different file names in the same directory?
Is it simply so the user doesn't get confused? or is there more to it in the background?

A convention of this site is that the question should be in the body of the post, not the title. Also, better questions will list the research that has been done prior to asking. Please EDIT your post, placing the question in the body, and telling us what research you have done trying to answer this yourself.

File names need to be unique so there is no confusion for the users and operating systems.  If you have 10 files all called test.txt in the same directory and you asked the computer to open or delete a file called test.txt, how would it know which one to open or delete?  Requiring all files (and folders) in the same folder being unique prevents this issue.
